# Just how light-sensitive is ethidium bromide?

Tags: molecular-biology, gel-electrophoresis, lab-reagents

One lab I was in was paranoid about keeping it in a foil-wrapped conical tube; my current lab leaves it out on the bench (and it works fine for staining gels). It's the same company/concentration in both cases, but this second lab uses it up much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

I found this reference in "[Molecular Biology: A Project Approach](http://books.google.com/books?id=PND76ZPTuXUC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=ethidium%20bromide%20photobleaching&source=bl&ots=rz8SAHMknF&sig=m-kJFB5HJ1GNBIffBZYvLG1NTWU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xMmvUYuiBpHxiQLqhoBA&ved=0CGgQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=ethidium%20bromide%20photobleaching&f=false)"

> A phenomenon called photobleaching occurs when ethidium bromide (EtBr) -stained DNA is illuminated by ultraviolet light.... This decreased fluorescence is presumably due to the dissociation of ethidium bromide from the DNA.

[Ethidium bromide fluoresces when it is in a hydrophobic environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethidium_bromide#Structure.2C_chemistry.2C_fluorescence), such as when its stuck between two base pair stacks in DNA- water quenches its fluorescence.

I also found [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0920586107004099) citing the fact that sunlight can break down EtBr but only when a catalyst of iron and titanium dioxide is there to catalyze the reaction.

A lot of the original characterization of EtBr as a stain is very old, so I couldn't access it directly online... It looks like the compound itself is pretty stable, but UV can, somehow interact with it when its bound to DNA to bleach it out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So on the bench in its bottle, ethidium bromide shouldn't be light-sensitive, unless there's iron and titanium dioxide contamination (or some hydrophobic substance)?  (also, could you link to the article? I'm pretty sure I found it earlier but I can't find it anymore)

Comment: I should think not. Eppendorf tubes are UV absorbant anyway.   I added a link to the article - thought I had it there.. (UV reference: http://www.eppendorfna.com/int/index.php?l=131&action=support&sitemap=4.1&productpage=41&catalognode=28832)

Answer (score 1):

In my current lab we just leave the bottle out (but use it up pretty quickly as we have 20+ people). But we do buy 5 bottles at a time and leave them in the same spot as the bottle that is in use (inside a hood, with the light always turned on) and we've never had a problem with degradation/expiration